# Ionic 2 Super Tabs not showing properly in browsers

Tags: ionic2, ionic-tabs

I'm using Ionic CLI v3.5.0 and Ionic2 Super Tabs v3.0.2
But the tabs are not displaying properly. On clicking the tabs, page changes but they are not displaying. 
[image]

Here is my app.module.ts. I have added SuperTabsModule.forRoot() as indicated in the docs.

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SuperTabsController} from 'ionic2-super-tabs';



import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { ExplorePage } from '../pages/explore/explore';
import { SuperTabsModule } from 'ionic2-super-tabs';
import { CoachingsPage } from '../pages/coachings/coachings';
import { TutorsPage } from '../pages/tutors/tutors';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    ExplorePage,
    CoachingsPage,
    TutorsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    SuperTabsModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    ExplorePage,
    CoachingsPage,
    TutorsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This is my tab.ts file. Here my pages doesn't use lazy loading so I haven't added SuperTabsModule here. I had added it but that didn't work.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CoachingsPage } from '../coachings/coachings';
import { TutorsPage } from '../tutors/tutors';


/**
 * Generated class for the ExplorePage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-explore',
  templateUrl: 'explore.html',
})
export class ExplorePage {

    tab1Root:any = CoachingsPage;
    tab2Root:any =  TutorsPage;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ExplorePage');
  }

}
```

Here's the tabs.html file:

```
<super-tabs>
<super-tab [root]="tab1Root" title="Top Tutors"></super-tab>
<super-tab [root]="tab2Root" title="Top Coaching"></super-tab>
</super-tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while but I had the same problem you have and I finally found that super-tabs CSS wasn't loaded.
You can try to retrieve the CSS and put it in one of your file as a test.